# Toggle one data-value in two different classes

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a demo panel which should switch two different background images.
you click on one link and two css classes are changed. 
the link contains data-field="bg1" and this value needs to change the css class: top-bg0 and bottombg0.

Here is a fiddle setup: 
**http://jsfiddle.net/wpcustoms/ktD3f/**

can somebody please assist me with the javascript?

that`s what I came up so far:

```
$('.panel ul li a').click(function(){
    var bgname = $(this).data('bg');
    $('#headerbar').removeClass('top-bg0').toggleClass(bgname);
    $('#footerbar').removeClass('bottom-bg0').toggleClass(bgname);
});
```

it currently removes the top-bg0 part and replaces it with the data-field (bg1,2,3) clicking on another link adds another class so it ends up with class="bg1 bg2 bg3" instead of changing the top-X and bottom-X value. Is there a way to FIND something in a class string and replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two elements only have the one class each, then you could simply use the no argument version of `.removeClass()` to remove whatever the current class is, then add the correct one:

```
$('.settings-panel .bg_pattern ul li').click(function(){
    var bgname = $(this).data('bg');
    $('#headerbar').removeClass().addClass('top-' + bgname);
    $('#footerbar').removeClass().addClass('bottom-' + bgname);
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ktD3f/1/)